# JCheckBox knowing if checkbox is selected or not

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcheckbox

To set a JCheckBox is using setSelected method with a boolean condition.
Which method do i use to get the boolean data out of the JCheckBox.
Thanks

Comment: umm can you rephrase your question? _to get the method out_ ??

Comment: Did you mean to check if the JCheckbox is selected? if so use isSelected()

Comment: Thank you very much..took me hours looking for the method. i thought it was like getSelected or getState.

Comment: LOL :-) it happens, sometimes, there are always somethings meant for others to show you :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean to check if the JCheckbox is selected? if so use [isSelected()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected%28%29)

You can also use an [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) in case you want to get notified about the check and uncheck!

Answer (score 3):

[isSelected()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected%28%29) is the method you looking for, I guess. This will return `false` if `JCheckBox` is `NOT Selected` and `true` if `Selected`.

Answer (score 3):

[This will help you.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected%28%29)